# Align buttons from left to right programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to align buttons from left to right programmatically in kotlin, but the buttons are going from top to bottom. Here is code to programmatically show and it will apply under `@+id/linearLayout`

**MainActivity.kt**

```
lateinit var linearLayout: LinearLayout
...
private fun createAndAddView()
{
    val array: Array<Int> = concat.toTypedArray()
    //val textView = TextView(this)
    //val btn = Button(this)

    val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    params.gravity = RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT;

    //btn.text = array.first().toString()
    for (i in array) {
        val btn = Button(this)
        //btn.width = 5
        //btn.height = 5
        btn.text = i.toString()
        btn.layoutParams = params
        linearLayout.addView(btn)
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MainActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberGenerated"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List Number 1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberGenerated2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List Number 2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberGenerated3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List Number 3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberGenerated4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List Number 4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberGenerated5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List Number 5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/collectedNumbers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="none" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGenerate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Generate" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/selectNumbers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select Numbers" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried to set `params.gravity = RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT;` to see if buttons align right, but it does not, it just goes from top to bottom, as shown in picture, how could I fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

instead of

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

in your LinearLayout @+id/linearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Alejandro H..You are doing this by wrong i will suggest you full code for creating list inside custom view...You have used Linearlayout for this.. Here is the code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardDbImage"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/blueDark"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_2sdp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Add Image"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/AppTheme.BoldFont"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This xml is for custom view which you store your number.

```
fun setupCustomView(count: Int) {

        binding.customView.removeAllViews()
        for (i in 0 until count) {

            arraySubMeter.add(SubMeters())
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_submeter, null)

            cardView[i] = inflater.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.cardDbImage)

            cardView[i]!!.setOnClickListener {

                selected = i
            }

            binding.customView.addView(inflater, binding.customView.childCount)

        }

    }
```

In above code you can add the numbers count which you want to add in this custom view and this will create horizontal list for you.